# After submitting 'Contact' message, how do I get it to stay on page and generate a text confirmation?

Tags: php, css

I've seen this question asked on Stack Overflow before, but haven't been able to get the previous solutions to work, for my site!

I have a 'Contact' page on a website ([staging.twotailsmedia.com)](http://staging.twotailsmedia.com).  And right now, the Contact page works and sends an email to the right place, but it generates a 'Thank you!' message on a new, separate, unformatted page.  Not what I want.  I want it to stay on the Contact page, generate the 'Thank you!' confirmation on the form next to the submit button.

Here's my Form's **HTML** from the index.html file:

```
<form method="POST" action="mail.php">

   <div class="field half first">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
   </div>

<div class="field half">
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</div>

<div class="field">
   <label for="message">Message</label>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

<ul class="actions">
   <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
   <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
</ul>

</form>
```

Here's the **PHP** from the mail.php file:

```
<?php

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";

        $recipient = "info@emailaddress.com";

        $subject = "A message from the Two Tails MEdia website!";

        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

        echo "Thank You! We'll get back to you.";
}
?>
```

Usually I'd just get a Contact Form plugin from Wordpress but I'm trying to do a non-WP page so I can get a deeper understanding of the web development process.

Comment: The keyword you should search for is "Ajax"

Comment: you can put your message in session and redirect user to previous url and apply a check on session if it has message key show message and destroy key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax to submit your form and by success show your message. Try this code:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'mail.php',
     data:$(this).serialize(),
     success:function(){
         $('form')[0].reset(); // to reset the form
         $('#contact').hide(); // to hide the Contact article
         $('#message').show(); // to show the hidden message
     }
   })
})
```

Comment: Hi Ferhad!  I created a separate .js file with your code and linked to it in my index.html file.  But even though my form works and the email gets sent though, the 'Thank you!' confirmation doesn't show up.

You can try it yourself: https://twotailsmedia.com/staging/#contact

How do we make the "Thank you!" show up?

Comment: make  thank message with id message like `<h1 id="message" style="display:none">Thank You!</h1>` and see the update of my code

Comment: Hey Ferhad- I added that line to my HTML file, but it's having no effect whatsoever.  Still no visible text confirmation!

Comment: Check the Script too

Comment: The Problem is that you have allready an `id=message` change it to something else in `h1` and in the `ajax`

Comment: Hey again Ferhad.  Thanks a lot for helping me out with this, but I still can't seem to get it working.  I changed the "message" ID in the HTML and .js file to "messageconf".  

The HTML file now says:

<h1 id="messageconf" style="display:none">Thank You!</h1>

And the .js line of code to:

$('#messageconf').show(); // to show the hidden message 

No dice. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: have you added the `<h1 id="contactMessage" style="display:none">Thank You!</h1>` to your html where contact form is?

Comment: Remove cache with Refresh `Ctrl+F5 `

Comment: The `h1` must be outside of `id=contact`, make it direct in the 
`<div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="messageconf" style="display:none">Thank You!</h1>`

Comment: Done, but still nothing.

(This is getting really embarrassing for me, now).

Comment: I have just now your link tested it work fine, you have may be a Cache. Refresh the Page with `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: Oh I see it now.  But now the 'Thank You' message just messes up my responsive/mobile view (image here: https://imgur.com/a/lgvlA).  The Thank you message also appears out of view on mobile, forcing the user to scroll up. Otherwise all they see is a blank background.  And they have to click their mouse in order to get back to the homepage.  Not a good user experience.

Is it possible to just have "Thank you" pop up on the actual form after it's submitted?  I think this is getting way more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: You have now the Message, you can give it a class and do some css like others. if you change the `h1` to somethig else like `div` for example, you must still use this id `id="contactMessage"` now do the css as you will. If You have any other question better ask it in new question

Comment: Yes, dont hie the form remove this `$('#contact').hide();` and put th `h1` in contact form

Comment: Okay, I'll try my best to get it to behave properly.  Thanks for your help (and your patience, with me)!